How can I use React without any bundling or transpilation
I want to use React as a library natively on the browser without any additional tooling such as webpack or Babel. In development, I am tired of having to transpile my React code into regular JavaScript code. This would also let me create a React application that benefits from ES6 modules, as they are also supported natively and do not require any additional tooling such as webpack or Babel.
I have looked into React.createElement but it is not very user friendly. Here is an example of React.createElement
React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello');
// <div>Hello</div>

I would like to use all of the features of React including hooks useState, useEffect, etc. Is there a viable solution to use React without needing to transpile or bundle?

What are you doing currently which causes you to get tired of having to transpile your react code? You shouldn't be having to do anything manually which would  cause annoyance. Vite is wonderful for handling this. There's no way around using createElement() if you're committed to not using a transpiler. That being said, I'd look at using CDN imports for the react hooks you'd like to use. IMO - it seems like way more of a headache to do things this way than just finding a normal workflow which works for you since your app would not be production ready

I have used ES Modules in development and they don't require any transpilation. When I try to go back to React development from native browser development I am disappointed by the build step as well as all of the bloat caused by the tooling.

I'm sure it's very situational then. For my workflow, I'd rather go through the "painful" process upfront of setting up Vite and then only having to run npm run dev or npm run watch once to build, as compared to adjusting the entire workflow to accommodate an unorthodox project structure. Seems pretty easy to me with Vite, but YMMV  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

@AustinDuling I have found vite SSR to be a bit opinionated and unflexible when it comes to dependency management. When it comes to serving actual production I need a solution that is fully configurable

Also it should be considered that importing a css file into a jsx component is nonsensical

there is a solution to use React without needing to transpile or bundle. I wrote the library Arche that provides a decent interface for working with React in pure JavaScript. Here are some examples:


// --- these lines can go inside a global.js file
const ReactElement = Arche(React)
const { Div, P, Button } = ReactElement
const { useState } = React
// ---


const Example = ReactElement(() => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return Div([
    P(`You clicked ${count} times`),
    Button({
      onClick() {
        setCount(count + 1)
      },
    }, 'Click me'),
  ])
})

ReactDOM.render(Example(), document.getElementById('react-root'))
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico@2.3.1/dist/rubico.min.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/arche@0.3.5/index.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="react-root"></div>
    </body>
  </html>



Here is the syntax:
Arche(React {
  createElement: (type, props?, children?)=>ReactElement,
}, options? {
  styled?: {
    div: function,
    p: funcion,
    span: function,
    // etc
  },
  styledMemoizationCap?: number, // defaults to 1000
}) -> ReactElement


Looks like Arche is 4 years old at this point. Was the point of your question to find out if there were other, newer solutions?

Yes, it is very strange to me that there would be ES6 modules but not a great ecosystem to use them
